# Stata: import delimited with duplicate variables

Tags: stata

I have a csv file with two identical columns:

```
X,X
0,0
1,1
2,2
```

I would like to import this into Stata 13, but it does not like importing the second `X` (since the names are the same):

```
. import delimited "filename.csv"
X already defined
Error creating variables
r(109);
```

Is there a simple way to force the import?

I do not want to specify the rows to import. The actual dataset has 100+ variables, and the duplicated variables are distributed throughout.
Similarly, I do not want to manually rename the variables.
I am fine if Stata wants to either drop or rename the second `X`.

As background, this csv file is being generated by some sloppy SQL code. The duplicated variables are precisely the variables I use for the joins. I could clean up the SQL code or pre-clean (with e.g. Python), but I would ideally like to have Stata force the import.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to open up the data file in Excel and change the variable names?

Comment: This particular csv has more than a million rows, which I believe will not load in Excel. But -- in general -- I would prefer not to do that... even for the cases where it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import delimited` was patched for this particular problem in the 07oct2013 update. To update Stata 13 type...

```
. update all
```

in the Stata Command window.

Answer (score 2):

Try `insheet`.

With this example data in a .csv file:

```
x,x,y,y
238965,586,127,192864
238965,586,127,192864
1074,198264,5186,2947
1074,198264,5186,2947
```

All variables are imported and the resulting names in Stata are:

```
x
v2
y
v4
```

The command would be:

```
insheet using "~/some/file.csv"
```

(I'm on Stata 12.1 and according to the Stata 13 [U] manual, `insheet` is superseded by `import delimited`, p.21.)

Comment: That works! And you're also right... insheet is no longer supported in Stata 13, but it still works. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Superseded commands work so older programs do not break when used with newer versions of Stata.

Comment: Be sure to read on both commands (superseded and new) so you know what you gain and lose, using each one.